# What is the meaning of ()->System.out.println("done")?

Tags: java, concurrency, lambda, java-8

In [Concurrency Interest](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2014-February/012320.html) link, there is a code which is like this:-

```
exec.schedule( ()-> System.out.println("done"),
         1, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

What is the meaning of ()-> ?

I checked in eclipse, it does not allow. But what was the intention of the thread-writer?

Comment: This is Java 8. `Runnable#run()` takes no arguments.

Comment: Shudder.  How to make Java code unreadable in 12 easy steps...

Comment: @Gray Ah come on. Play with it for a day and you'll be comfortable with it.

Comment: Oh I know that I can get comfortable with it @SotiriosDelimanolis.  I just think it lowers the readability of the language to save on characters.  It's a cute language feature but I'm not sure it is going to improve code maintainability.

Comment: @Gray I also think that a it's better if the language is more expressive and that this won't do much for maintainability. However, I don't think they made lambdas just for that.

Comment: Expressiveness enthusiasts often forget that code is written a lot less often than it is read. Readability and understandability should come first, not expressiveness. I think java is one of the few to get this right, but going in the wrong direction. :/

Comment: @eis - They started down that path with generics.  (I'm not saying that the concept is bad, but to simply copy the C++ scheme was stupid.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Lambda](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) syntax from JDK8.

It is pretty similar (but not exactly same) to

```
exec.schedule(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 7):

That is the Java 8 syntax for [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#exec(..)` method expects a `Runnable` argument. `Runnable` is a functional interface because it only contains one `abstract` method. As such, the compiler can infer that you are defining a new `Runnable` instance with the lambda.

The parts between `()` are the `run()` method's parameters, ie. none. The part after the `->` is the body of the method.